# onPurchasesUpdated called multiple times

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I have set up in-app billing on an Android app (java). When I call `launchBillingFlow` on the `BillingClient`:

```
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                .build();
        BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            //the system displays the Google Play purchase screen
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Billing failed: + " + billingResult.getDebugMessage());
        }
```

This is what my `onPurchasesUpdated` (from `PurchasesUpdatedListener`) looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                && purchases != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                for (String sku : purchase.getSkus()) {
                    if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                        if (skuConsumables.contains(sku)) {
                            handlePurchaseConsumable(purchase);
                        } else if (skuNonconsumables.contains(sku)) {
                            handlePurchaseNonconsumable(purchase);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
            billingServiceListener.receivePurchaseError();
        } else {
            // Handle any other error codes.
            billingServiceListener.receivePurchaseError();
        }
    }
```

`onPurchasesUpdated` is called six times, each time with a responseCode of `OK`. Twice `onPurchasesUpdated` is called with zero purchases, that's fine. What I am confused about is how to deal with the four times `onPurchasesUpdated` is called with one purchase. And it seems as though each of these four purchase objects are indistinguishable - the same `packageName`, `acknowledged`, `orderId`, `productId`, `purchaseState`, `purchaseToken`, etc.

To complicate things, for consumable in-app billing, (these are consumable) I am then calling `ConsumeResponseListener` and `onConsumeResponse` is also returning four times, each time with responseCode of OK.

```
private void handlePurchaseConsumable(Purchase purchase) {

        ConsumeParams consumeParams =
                ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                        .build();

        ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // Handle the success of the consume operation.

                }
            }
        };
        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, listener);
    }
```

Is this behaviour seen by others? I am using static responses while in development, could this be the reason? If people are seeing this, how do you deal with this - do you keep track of what purchase you have attempted, and then when the first response is returned do you register that the purchase was successful and ignore subsequent times that `onPurchasesUpdated` returns a purchase if you weren't expecting a payment? Though I've seen that Android permits cash purchases with `enablePendingPurchases`, so that can't be a solution...

Answer (score 4):

**This can happen for 2 reasons.**

1. if you are using an outdated version of the `google-billing` API.
2. if you forgot to destroy the billing client at the finish of the activity.

Comment: 1. I am using 4.0.0.              [newline]. 
2. I only have one activity (use fragments)

Comment: I mean, if you're `start connection` more than one time called, then make sure that you have to destroy it before a new connection with `billingClient.endConnection()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. `billingClient.startConnection` is only called once, and `onBillingSetupFinished` is only triggered once with a responseCode of OK. I know this because I log to the console when these two events occur.

Comment: billingClient.endConnection() solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've checked [Samples for Google Play In-app Billing](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples) and how I can see the main idea of usage the billing client is to use it with activity/fragment lifecycles. So your billing client should implement `DefaultLifecycleObserver`. We need it to have connect/disconnect billing client use UI lifecycle. In other case we could have few instances of billing client in the App and few listeners that will be triggered with success purchase in same time. So code should looks like:

Activity/Fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  lifecycle.addObserver(billingLifecycleManager)
}
```

BillingLifecycleManager:

```
class BillingLifecycleManager { 

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(app)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()
        if (billingClient.isReady) {
            billingClient.startConnection(...)
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
          super.onDestroy(owner)
          if (billingClient.isReady) {
              billingClient.endConnection()
          }
    }

}
```